# Use dynamically created Sequelize Instance in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

In order to allow multi tenancy I'm creating request scoped instances of Sequelize depending on a tenant's subdomain, e.g. team1.example.com creates an instance accessing database schema "team1". Researching this topic lead me to the example of async configuration for Sequelize using a config service, which looks like this:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope, Request } from "@nestjs/common";
import { REQUEST } from "@nestjs/core";
import { SequelizeModuleOptions, SequelizeOptionsFactory} from "@nestjs/sequelize";

@Injectable({scope:Scope.REQUEST})
export class SequelizeConfigService implements SequelizeOptionsFactory {
    
    constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request:Request){}

    createSequelizeOptions(): SequelizeModuleOptions {

      let domain:string[]
      let database='default'

      domain=this.request['headers']['host'].split('.')

      if(domain[0]!='localhost' && domain[0]!='127' && domain[0]!='www' && domain.length >2){
        database=domain[0]
      }

    return {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'localuser',
        password: 'supersecretpassword',
        database: database,
        autoLoadModels: true,
        synchronize: true,
    };
  }
}
```

The configuration is then used when importing Sequelize in a module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
          useClass:SequelizeConfigService
        }),
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([User])
      ],
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

This works fine but this mechanism creates a new instance (and thus a connection) with every request which will lead to performance issues eventually.

Is there a way to store Sequelize instances / connections which have already been created for a tenant  to re-use them for subsequent requests?

Comment: Have you looked up setting up Sequelize with Factory Pattern?

Comment: I know how to do this with TypeORM as you can access the connection there but no idea how this works with Sequelize.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, i have created an issue on their repo https://github.com/nestjs/sequelize/issues/990
@PeterBienek did you manage to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can install this NPM module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelizemultitenantmodule
npm i sequelizemultitenantmodule

Then change

`SequelizeModule.forRootAsync`

to

`SequelizeMultiTenantModule.forRootAsync`

and your code should work.